# calculating covariance

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be random variable with normal distribution $N(100,100)$
and $Y = 4X - 300$

I need to calculate covariance.

So far we know
$EX = 100$

$EY=E(4x-300)=4EX - 300 = 4*100-300 =400-300 = 100$

The formula for covariance is

$E(XY)-EXEY$

$E(X*(4X-300))-100*100$

$E(4X^{2}-300X)-10000$

$E(4X^{2})-E(300X)-10000$

$4E(X^2) - 300EX - 100000$

$4E(X^2) - 300*100 - 10000$

$4E(X^2) - 20000$

However my question is, without having density function ( for calcualting E(X) or E(X^2) using integration, or any set, how can i calculate $E(X^2)$?

Is there any shorcut or i did some mistake in my calculations?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

By expanding and simplifying the definition of variance, we obtain:
$$\mbox{Var}(X) \equiv \mathbb{E}\{[X- \mathbb{E}(X)]^2\} = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2.$$
Since we know that $\mathbb{E}(X) = 100$ and $\mbox{Var}(X) = 100$, it follows that: 
$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mbox{Var}(X) + \mathbb{E}(X)^2 = 100 + 100^2 = 10100.$$

Answer (score 0):

You are given that the variance of X is 100. You can calculate E[$X^2$] by solving Var[X] = E[$X^2$] - $E[X]^2$.